# change font color on linux terminal

Tags: terminal

i want to change the font color of everything i write in the linux terminals (eg the one accessible at `ctrl+alt+f1`) to green. my default tty font color is white, but i would like it to be green. i have tried

```
setterm -term linux -foreground green -clear
```

but this just changes the color of the cursor. i want to change the color of the font - so that it looks the same as the following xterm configuration:

```
xterm -foreground green
```

Comment: FYI, CTRL+ALT+F1 would be /dev/TTY1/

Comment: correct. is this always the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just needed to include the `-store` setting. the following does the trick perfectly:

```
setterm -foreground green -store
```

Answer (score 0):

add to

~/.bashrc

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0232323" #black
    echo -en "\e]P82B2B2B" #darkgrey
    echo -en "\e]P1D75F5F" #darkred
    echo -en "\e]P9E33636" #red
    echo -en "\e]P287AF5F" #darkgreen
    echo -en "\e]PA98E34D" #green
    echo -en "\e]P3D7AF87" #brown
    echo -en "\e]PBFFD75F" #yellow
    echo -en "\e]P48787AF" #darkblue
    echo -en "\e]PC7373C9" #blue
    echo -en "\e]P5BD53A5" #darkmagenta
    echo -en "\e]PDD633B2" #magenta
    echo -en "\e]P65FAFAF" #darkcyan
    echo -en "\e]PE44C9C9" #cyan
    echo -en "\e]P7E5E5E5" #lightgrey
    echo -en "\e]PFFFFFFF" #white
    clear #for background artifacting
fi
```

http://phraktured.net/linux-console-colors.html

Comment: i did this then ran `. .bashrc` and it seems to have enabled 16bit colors for my tty1, but the font color has not changed from the default white. do i need to issue another command to actually set the font color to green?

Comment: actually i think [it just modified the default colors without adding anything new.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors) they look better, but unfortunately its not an answer to my question. -1

Answer (score 0):

this command channges font colour>>
tput setaf 4

this command changes background colour>>
tput setab 2

change the no's to change colours
0=black
7=white

also set this cmd in alias to change colours in 2 letters

> > alias c1='tput setaf 4'

write these alias in .bashrc file to make them permanent.