# How to reset default terminal text color?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I set my default terminal text color to the default setting (white)?

The default text color in my terminal is red for some reason. I can output white text using color codes. I have tried completely reinstalling Ubuntu for Windows, with no luck.

For clarity: When I reinstalled Ubuntu, the first text asking you to create a username and password is red.

Comment: Possible duplicate, from late answer here - [change font color on linux terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/651405/change-font-color-on-linux-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in Ubuntu 18.04. Open a terminal session, Edit, Preferences, and along the top you see Text, Colors and set colors there

Answer (score 1):

[mulllhausen](https://superuser.com/users/90542/mulllhausen)'s answer was what I needed. My initial settings were correct, but some terminal programs leave the text colors in an odd state.

`setterm -foreground white -store`

see https://superuser.com/a/651431/382138

Comment: [Linked question as possible dupe to this one. Thanks for finding it.]